# Regex to capture characters between the last white space character and the end of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to determine the characters between the last white space characer and the end of the string.

#### Example

```
Input:   "this and that"

Output: "that"
```

I have tried the regex below but it doesnt work!

```
var regex = /[\s]$/
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can do without regex

```
var result = string.substring(string.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);
```

Using regex

```
result = string.match(/\s[a-z]+$/i)[0].trim();
```

Comment: Assuming there IS a space in the string at all

Comment: If not `lastIndexOf` returns `-1`, `1` gets added so the substring starts at `0` and the entire string is returned. So exactly what was asked for.

Comment: For the regex, I'd use `/\S+$/`, but the substring equivalent is obviously better.

Comment: @cbuckley yes, your regex is better.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use simple regex pattern

```
\S+$
```

#### Javascript test code:

```
document.writeln("this and that".match(/\S+$/));
```

#### Output:

```
that
```

Test it **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/77Eu2/)**.

Answer (score 0):

You could just remove everything up to the last space.

```
s.replace(/.* /, '')
```

Or, to match any white space...

```
s.replace(/.*\s/, '')
```

Answer (score -1):

Your example matches just one space character at the end of the string. Use

```
/\s\S+$/
```

to match any number.